# get user name from table which not in second table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

i am creating groups for my website. i have following tables

**user** table which contain all user details
 **cc_group_member** table for users group details in this i have user id, group id 
 **communication_center_groups** table for groups .

i want to search user for add in a group. but when i search then it show duplicate data. problem is this.. which user is alreay a member of that group it is also show in search result.

i have 4 invitation status in group table which reffer

0- send request

1-accpet

2-reject

3-cancel.

i want if user reject or cancel request thay also show in result but only 1 time it show 2 times in my result. please help..
thanx.

```
SELECT u.*,cc.invitation 
FROM user u 
  left join (select distinct(user_id),invitation 
             from cc_group_member 
             where group_id='$groupId' 
             and (invitation = '3' or invitation = '2') ) as cc ON u.id = cc.user_id 
where (u.username like '".$condition."%' or u.first_name like '".$condition."%' or last_name like '".$condition."%') 
and u.type !='1' and u.type = '$user_type'  
ORDER BY u.username

SELECT u.*,cc.invitation 
FROM user u left join (select distinct(user_id),invitation 
                       from cc_group_member 
                       where group_id='10' 
                       and (invitation = '3' or invitation = '2') ) as cc ON u.id = cc.user_id 
where (u.username like '1%' or u.first_name like '1%' or last_name like '1%') 
 and u.type !='1' and u.type = '5' 
ORDER BY u.username
```

Comment: What is the idea behind the left join to a query rather than directly joining it to the cc_group_member table?

Comment: it will help if you update table wise data as an example, what results you are getting by your query and what results you want.

Answer (score 0):

I could not understand your question.but if your are having duplicate result you can make use of select distinct and  for your second part you can add another field in database which tells whether this user is member or not

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

simply use union with your different condition and get your all records